# Must define one of 'pointcut' or 'pointcut-ref' on <advisor>

Tags: java, xml, spring, aop, spring-aop

This is the aspect class

```
public class TransactionAspect {

    public void beforeAnything() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("In the aspect");    
    }   

    public void beforeWithdrawalTransaction() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("In the aspect");
    }

    public void beforeDepositTransaction() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("In the aspect");
    }

    public void beforeBalance() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("In the aspect");
    }
}
```

**This is the xml configuration file with my aspect I have tried different ways but still its not working**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy></aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <aop:config>

        <aop:pointcut id="forAnything" expression="execution(* com.pack.service.*.*(..))"  />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="myAspectBean" pointcut="forAnything" id="interceptor" ></aop:advisor>

        <aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="myAspectBean">

            <aop:before  method="beforeWithdrawalTransaction"  />
            <aop:before  method="beforeDepositTransaction" />
            <aop:before method="beforeBalance"/>

        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>       

    <bean id="myAspectBean" class="com.pack.aspect.TransactionAspect"/>
</beans>
```

**When I try to load my application, I get this error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Must define one of 'pointcut' or 'pointcut-ref' on <advisor> tag.
Offending resource: class path resource [Spring.xml]
Aspect: id='myAspect'
    -> Advice (before)
```

Comment: I would advise you to move away from XML configuration for Spring.  Annotations are preferred.  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: The reason I'm trying to use XML is because my pointcut was not working when I was using annotations

Comment: XML won't fix it.   The problem is the pointcut definition.  Look at the docs link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to add the property,pointcut-ref ="pointcut_id",to the tag